# Setup a Google Custom Goal with an event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to setup A/B testing using Google experiments where I want to check if users would click a specific button more based on look and feel of the website. These are the steps I plan to follow.

1. Setup an google-tag to capture the button click event ( Done and Verified)
2. Setup an Goal with the new event
3. Setup an experiment with the goal in step 2

I am stuck at step 2, (Check image below)

[image]

Comment: I will also suggest adding a new view for experiments as it will affect your overall conversion rate for your default view which may skew your reporting data. Just a heads up if not done already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. The field values are the same as the values in the Events -> Overview section

eg:

- Event Category: `Button Click`
- Event Action: `Click`
- Event Label: `/mypagename.html`

These were set when i created a event tag using google-tag manager.

For the Value field, I had to keep it empty since I am not tracking any values